# Why is one character missing in the query result?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Take a look at the code:

```
string expression = "x & ~y -> (s + t) & z";
var exprCharsNoWhitespace = expression.Except( new[]{' ', '\t'} ).ToList();
var exprCharsNoWhitespace_2 = expression.Replace( " ", "" ).Replace( "\t", "" ).ToList();

// output for examination
Console.WriteLine( exprCharsNoWhitespace.Aggregate( "", (a,x) => a+x ) );
Console.WriteLine( exprCharsNoWhitespace_2.Aggregate( "", (a,x) => a+x ) );

// Output:
// x&~y->(s+t)z
// x&~y->(s+t)&z
```

I want to remove all whitespace from the original string and then get the individual characters.
The result surprized me.
The variable exprCharsNoWhitespace contains, as expected, no whitespace, but unexpectedly, only *almost* all of the other characters. The last occurence of '&' is missing, the Count of the list is 12.
Whereas exprCharsNoWhitespace_2 is completely as expected: Count is 13, all characters other than whitespace are contained.

The framework used was .NET 4.0.
I also just pasted this to csharppad (web-based IDE/compiler) and got the same results.

Why does this happen?

---

**EDIT**:
Allright, I was unaware that Except is, as pointed out by Ryan O'Hara, a set operation. I hadn't used it before.

```
// So I'll continue just using something like this:
expression.Where( c => c!=' ' && c!='\t' )

// or for more characters this can be shorter: 
expression.Where( c => ! new[]{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}.Contains(c) ).
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`Except` produces a *set* difference.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Your expression isn’t a set, so it’s not the right method to use. As to why the `&` specifically is missing: it’s because it’s repeated. None of the other characters is.

Comment: D'oh! I was unaware that aspect of the method.

Comment: Wow, this is awful naming. I'd have never expected this.

Comment: @Mehrdad - I'm curious what you'd do to fix the naming here? Enumerable has a number of "set-based" methods and they use conventional set terminology - Intersect, Union, Except.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: `Difference`? Or even better, `SetDifference`, if we could have the others be `SetUnion` etc... at least "difference" is a standard set theory term so you'd have a clue what the cause might be.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: For that matter, why *should* it even convert things into sets? Why shouldn't it keep the order and the repetition count? There could just be a `Unique()` method that makes something a set; there's no reason to have a set-based method at all, really.

Answer (score 4):

Ryan already answered your question as asked, but I'd like to provide you an alternative solution to the problem you are facing.  If you need to do a lot of string manipulation, you may find regular expression pattern matching to be helpful.  The examples you've given would work something like this:

```
string expression = "x & ~y -> (s + t) & z";
string pattern = @"\s";
string replacement = "";
string noWhitespace = new Regex(pattern).Replace(expression, replacement);
```

Or for the second example, keep everything the same except the pattern:

```
string pattern = "[abcd]";
```

Keep the Regex object stored somewhere rather than creating it each time if you're going to use the same pattern a lot.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned `.Except(...)` is a set operation so it drops duplicates.

Try just using `.Where(...)` instead:

```
string expression = "x & ~y -> (s + t) & z";
var exprCharsNoWhitespace =
    String.Join(
        "",
        expression.Where(c => !new[] { ' ', '\t' }.Contains(c)));
```

This gives:

```
x&~y->(s+t)&z
```